# Can't import tensorflow in Jupyter

Tags: python, tensorflow

The 'import tensorflow as tf" code seems to be giving me an Import Error response when I use that code in my Jupyter notebook. It would be important to note that I use Windows 10.

However, I am very sure that I downloaded tensorflow correctly. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7NUZ.png)
1. I created a conda environment
2. Activated it
3. downloaded tensorflow
4. updated the version
5. used pip install IPykernel

Any tips? Thank you so much, Stack Overflow Community!

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17393

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have installed the `tensorflow` library inside the environment.

Or else you can try coming out of the environment and trying again.

Comment: Yeah i can confirm that its definitely in there - i used the pip show tensorflow @Parzival